# Display Text for Enum

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, enums

HI 
I have the following enum

```
public enum Priority : byte 
    {
        A=1,
        B+ = 2,
        B=4,
        C=8,
        D=16,
        E=32
    }
```

I want to add `B+` in the enum but it is giving me error

Comment: Of course, `B+` is not a valid name for a enum value. In fact it's not even a valid name for an identifier. What is your actual issue?

Comment: if you need custom text for enum members try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187085/string-to-enum-conversion-in-c-sharp

Comment: You can add user friendly description for enum like done [here]

[here]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331487/how-to-have-userfriendly-names-for-enumerations

Comment: Another answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424366/c-sharp-string-enums

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can add user friendly description for enum like below :

```
enum MyEnum 
{ 
    [Description("This is black")] 
    Black, 
    [Description("This is white")] 
    White 
}
```

**Ref. Link :** [How to have userfriendly names for enumerations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331487/how-to-have-userfriendly-names-for-enumerations)

Answer (score 5):

How about using a valid identifier like B_Plus?

Comment: It is the business requirement to show B+ in drop down

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's giving you an error because your code is wrong. You can't make "B+" an enum value because there's a plus sign. Same reason you can't declare `int B+`. Use a different name.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use + as a name identifier because it's a math operator or string concatenator... it can't be used with enums.  Use an alternative syntax, or use an alternative approach.  You could consider a state design pattern:

http://www.dofactory.com/patterns/PatternState.aspx#_self2