# Using localized enum as DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, enums

I've lots of enums in my app. Most of them are used on combos like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoControlador))
```

Now I'd like to localize them like this: [Localizing enum descriptions attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes/571555#571555)

How can I combine them? My first thought was to override the `ToString` method with an extension method, but that's not possible =(

Comment: Diego, what stops you from applying this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes/571555#571555 ??

Comment: *How can I combine them?* What do you mean? Making a string representation of flagged enum values?

Comment: How would I change the line `someControl.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoControlador));` to use that approach?

Comment: @GertArnold what I want is that the method EnumDescription be called always that some code wants to convert my enum into string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the other article as a basis, you can create an extension method like this:

```
public static class LocalizedEnumExtensions
{
    private static ResourceManager _resources = new ResourceManager("MyClass.myResources",
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetLocalizedNames(this IEnumerable enumValues)
    {
        foreach(var e in enumValues)
        {
            string localizedDescription = _resources.GetString(String.Format("{0}.{1}", e.GetType(), e));
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(localizedDescription))
            {
                yield return e.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return localizedDescription;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(TipoControlador)).GetLocalizedNames();
```

Technically, this extension method will accept any array, and you can't restrict it to only work on an enum, but you could add extra validation inside the extension method if you feel it's important:

```
if(!e.GetType().IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("{0} is not a valid Enum!", e.GetType()));
```

Comment: If I do that then I won't be able to convert the combo.Value to the enum because it will have a string.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here, the first is how to localize enums which is solved by [Localizing enum descriptions attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes/571555#571555).

The second is how to display the localized name whilst using the enum's value. This can be solved by creating a simple wrapper object such as:

```
public sealed class NamedItem
{
    private readonly string name;
    private readonly object value;

    public NamedItem (string name, object value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Name { get { return name; } }
    public object Value { get { return value; } }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This provides a generic re-usable class for any drop down box where you might want to show a different name for an item than the item itself provides (eg enums, ints, etc).

Once you have this class, you can set the drop down's `DisplayMember` to `Name` and `ValueMember` to `Value`. This will mean that `dropdown.SelectedValue` will still return your enum.

Comment: I don't like that here is object instead of specific type.

Comment: It doesn't make a huge difference, since dropdown.SelectedValue returns an object, it can easily be changed to be a generic type if you want to be more specific though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but this may help some people.
You can just handle the Format event of the ComboBox control (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.format.aspx), and add your text logic in it.

```
    private void ComboBoxFormat(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Value = GetDescription(e.Value);
    }

    public static string GetDescription(object item)
    {
        string desc = null;

        Type type = item.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(item.ToString());
        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                desc = (attrs[0] as DescriptionAttribute).Description;
            }
        }

        if (desc == null) // Description not found
        {
            desc = item.ToString();
        }

        return desc;
    }
```

With this, the ComboBox control still holds enum values rather than strings.