# store static data in Database or file system

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, xml, localization

Currently we are storing static data (e.g. gender, marital status, state etc..) into DB by creating different lookup tables (gender, state etc....).  We have almost 10 lookup tables. All of these tables are FK to transaction table - user (which stores all users demographic info). Some of these static data are also used by other transaction tables. Now while fetching a user info we normally put a join to these tables and get the related text. Certainly these many joins can create performance issues and also as per MSDN we shouldn't have more than 5 joins in a select query. Now to avoid this we can move all the static data to xml file and read it from them. Certainly we will cache the xml data so it will be only read once. I would like to know is that a good approach. I can see the below trade offs-

1. Cannot maintain referential integrity.
2. while using load balancing all the servers need to have the xml file.

I don't want the values to be in enum as these needs to be localized. The only advantage I see keeping in xml is that it reduces overhead to DB (creating 10 tables). I can very well cache the static data stored in DB. So would like to know that still storing data in xml is a good choice over DB?

PS: Application is Web app and developed in .net 3.5.

Comment: I think the MSDN statement on the number of joins should be considered a guideline, and not a rule.  Is there a specific problem that you're wanting to solve?  Are these queries currently performing slowly?  If so, there may be other approaches that you could take to improve performance, such as indexing, caching within your application, and finally denormalization as just a last-ditch solution.

Comment: as of now no as the data is low but certainly it will come up when we will have 25k rows into the table. Moreover just to make it clear how the data will store in user table-  relevant id of static data(e.g. user table will have column stateid and which will hold id of the state)will be stored for that user, static text will be stored in xml and will retrieve the appropriate text based on the id.

Comment: Disclaimer: The following is MY own shortcuts that I have developed to speed up these types of issues based on years and years of db stuff going back to dBase. I key lookup tables that are usually static and have small row counts by the string(i.e. PhoeType: Mobile, Home, Work, etc). I do not key them by an integer ID. Then you do not need the join to display the text, but it will still enforce integrity for you and provide lookups as needed.

Comment: @Punit This is just a random guess considering I don't know what type of hardware your Sql Server runs on, but I don't think that you'll see performance issues with this design (assuming proper indexing) until you get into the millions and millions of rows...  Sql Server is very good at querying relational data such as this.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - That's assuming he's on SQLServer, but all major RDBMSs can handle that kind of load trivially.  Most of them would also keep small tables like that in-memory (effectively), too, especially if they're queried often.

Comment: @GDF - Your scheme is not amenable to localization, which the OP mentions he needs.  Unless the string you're storing is some 'default' language, but that doesn't help for _other_ languages, so you're back to where you started...

Comment: @X-Zero- I am not sure if i have got it correctly, but this is how currently we support localization in DB- we have locale table for every lookup, e.g. state has statelocale which will contain language(US,French etc..), based on the language we filter the text.

Comment: @X-Zero Missed the localization need...

Comment: @Punit - Sounds about how I'd do it, so far.  Please note that, while every `JOIN` _does_ cost (in terms of performance), most RDBMSs will be able to handle a **lot** of table references - I've written statements with almost 20 table references, but the limit on DB2 is 100+ (depends on version).  For stuff like static lookup tables with 'few' rows, the system will potentially keep it in memory.  Alternatively, if your system supports it, consider materialized/indexed views.

Comment: You can use enums and then localize the enum description  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569298/localizing-enum-descriptions-attributes

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Don't use synthetic keys, i.e. your MaritalStatus table has columns msId and StatusText (e.g. 1, "Married"), and is keyed on msId.  Your data table then holds an msId field, and must always join to the MaritalStatus table to get the text.
Instead, just store the useful text, and set this as the unique key.  In this case, the table will hold just the single text column ("Married", "Single", etc.).
The data table then has an MStatus text field, with a foreign key to the MaritalStatus table.  But when you read the data table, you already have the status text, so you don't need to join to the reference table.  The constraint maintains data integrity.
Of course this doesn't work if you need to store multiple columns in the reference table, but I would still reccomend avoiding synthetic keys where possible, unless the natural key is large enough to cause storage issues.

### Solution 2

Have a single ReferenceData table.  Create columns for Type, Id, and Value.
Use the Type field instead of a separate table name, e.g. "MaritalStatus".
Join to the reference table specifying a literal value for the Type column, and then match on Id or Value.  This should probably work in FK constraints too (but would need checking on different database software).